# Binding events inside click method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was told previously that I should not bind events inside of a function. What would be my best option to get around this current issue? I click on a link and from that link I want to get some properties. Here is how I am currently doing it.

```
$(".portfolioLink").click(function(){

            // Show slide and portfolio piece info
            $(".inner-content.portfolio").show();

            // Reset slides timer and pagination
            clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
            $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");

            // Get ID from link that is clicked.
            var slideID = $(this).parent().attr("id");

            $("#previous").click(function() {
                slideID--;
                clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
                $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");
                portfolioSwitch(slideID);
            });

            $("#next").click(function() {
                slideID++;
                clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
                $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");
                portfolioSwitch(slideID);
            });
}
```

I have two buttons that go back and forth which are the next and previous buttons. Depending on what link I click, I want to go forward or back. What's the best way of having these click events outside of the `$(".portfolioLink")` click event and at the same time get those properties from the portfolio link?

Comment: can you also post your html codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was told previously that I should not bind events inside of a function

It is not a problem to bind event handlers inside a function, only if that function is another event handler. If that other event handler would be executed multiple times (like in your case), you would bind (add) a new event handler every time which you normally don't want to do.

---

You can use a shared variable (a variable in a common scope)... if `slideID` is not set, don't do anything if `#next` or `#previous` are clicked:

```
var slideID;

$(".portfolioLink").click(function(){
    // ...

    // Get ID from link that is clicked.
    slideID = $(this).parent().attr("id");
});

$("#previous").click(function() {
    if(typeof slideID !== 'undefined') {
       // ...
    }
});

$("#next").click(function() {
    if(typeof slideID !== 'undefined') {
       // ...
    }
});
```

Or you initialise `slideID` with a default slide number.

Answer (score 6):

Binding the click events inside another click event means that everytime a `.portfolioLink` is clicked, a new click function is bound to the #previous/#next button, so it would increment twice if `.portfolioLink` was clicked twice, three increments if clicked three times etc. You can use a variable in a higher to scope to solve the issue, like so:

```
var slideID = 0;

$(".portfolioLink").click(function() {
    $(".inner-content.portfolio").show();

    clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
    $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");

    slideID = $(this).parent().attr("id");
}

$("#previous, #next").click(function() {
    slideID = this.id=='next' ? slideID+1 : slideID-1;
    clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
    $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");
    portfolioSwitch(slideID);
});
​
```

Comment: +1 sharing the click event handler for both buttons makes sense.

Comment: @FelixKling - thanks, upvoted yours aswell, as they are both pretty much the same idea.